# Crystal Reports conditional text output

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, conditional-statements

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCvQb.png)I have been asked to write a formula that will conditionally display text on a single field if item numbers on an order are a of a certain value.

So if any of the items on an order match the following values:

```
>{oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '022471-2000'
>{oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142846-003'
>{oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '202522-2000'
>{oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '022468-2000'
>{oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '022471-2000'
>{oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '202522-2010'
>{oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '202258-01'
>{oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142845-002'
>{oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142847-20204'
>{oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142848-01402'
>{oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142848-01408'
>{oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142849-001'
```

Then return a text line saying "Class VI Certification Required"
Otherwise nothing should be printed.

Currently I have:

```
If {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '022471-2000'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142846-003'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '202522-2000'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '022468-2000'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '022471-2000'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '202522-2010'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '202258-01'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142845-002'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142847-20204'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142848-01402'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142848-01408'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142849-001'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else ""
```

This works to a point, but it generates extra pages for every part, the report should be a single page.
How can I get this to print out the text field on the single page if any of the part numbers match without it generating a new page for each?

Comment: May you show a snapshot of your design and another of your output?

Comment: @heringer I have added an example

Comment: so the problem is that instead of looking for one of those parts and returning the line if they exist, it prints the line if one exists and stops, if one doesnt exist it keeps looking and posts for each item that doesnt meet the criteria.

Comment: So, if i got it... If you supress the section when the formula returns ""... Would you get what you want?

Comment: I apologize, i was not alerted to a response. Yes that is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using 
edit formula:

```
If {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '022471-2000'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142846-003'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '202522-2000'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '022468-2000'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '022471-2000'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '202522-2010'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '202258-01'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142845-002'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142847-20204'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142848-01402'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142848-01408'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else if {oeordlin_sql.item_no} = '142849-001'
Then "Class VI certificate Required"
else "suppress"
```

then going to select expert:
 and setting @Class VI Cert to "is not equal to 'suppress'"

then Format field:
Suppress If Duplicated